# How do I import an IIFE-based JavaScript module into an Angular TypeScript app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, iife

So I have a third-party SDK written as an oldschool IIFE based module. In other words it looks something like this:

```
var ThirdPartySDK = (function() {
  var export = {};

  // Add some methods to export

  return export;
})();
```

You would then be expected to use it by referencing it on the global scope like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="lib/ThirdPartySDK.js">
    <script>
      ThirdPartySDK.foo();
    <\script>
  <\body>
<\html>
```

I could still use it this way of course, but is that really the best practice with Angular and TypeScript? Is there some way to set things up with angular/TypeScript/webpack so that I can use a proper import statement? Something like this:

```
import { ThirdPartySDK } from '../lib/ThirdPartySDK.js';
ThirdPartySDK.foo();
```

Answer (score 6):

The best way to have a proper import statement for the actual *value* of `ThirdPartySDK` is to refactor the script to a module that exports this value. The following snippet allows you to use the import statement as showed:

```
export const ThirdPartySDK = {
    foo() { console.log('Doing foo'); }
};
```

For big libraries refactoring is not always that easy, so I see 2 approaches that do not involve too much refactoring:

---

**1. Export the `ThirdPartySDK` variable**

You could simply make a module out of the IIFE file by exporting the current `IThirdPartySDK` variable (returned by the IIFE), and then import it as you showed:

```js
export const ThirdPartySDK = (function() {
    var _export = {};

    // Add some methods to export

    return _export;
})();
```

Note that if you want to have some useful information about the shape of `ThirdPartySDK` you would have to add a type annotation to the `const` declaration, and if `SomeType` (see below) does not yet exist you'll have to write it yourself:

```
export const ThirdPartySDK: SomeType = (function() {
// ...
```

At this point Typescript will start to complain about the IIFE expression not being assignable to SomeType; the quick 'solution' to tell typescript to pretend the expression evaluates to a value of type `SomeType` using the `as` keyword:

```
export const ThirdPartySDK: SomeType = (function() {
    // ...
})() as SomeType;
```

**2. Keep the `<script>` tag and declare the variable**

Another option it to keep the script tag, import nothing, and [*declare* the variable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#global-variables) and its expected type in typescript:

(But also in this case you might have to provide type definitions yourself)

```
interface SomeType {
    // SDK type shape goes here...
}

declare const ThirdPartySDK: SomeType;
```

Comment: Thanks! I am a little reticent to modify the source file with an export statement, because I want to be able to just drop in a new version if/when it comes. The declaration might be the only way to go, but I was hoping there was something clever I could do like isolate/export the IIFE's global scope in a separate module or something.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the third-party SDK in a TypeScript module using a hack with `eval`.

Let's say that ThirdPartySDK.js looks like this:

```
var ThirdPartySDK = (function () {
    var exports = {
        foo: function () { console.log("Hello, world!"); }
    };
    return exports;
})();
```

You would then create a ThirdPartySDK-wrapper.ts module that looks something like this:

```ts
import * as fs from 'fs';
const script = fs.readFileSync('../lib/ThirdPartySDK.js').toString();

global.eval(script);

//@ts-ignore
export default ThirdPartySDK;
```

The `@ts-ignore` directive is required to keep the TypeScript compiler from complaining about not finding a declaration for the `ThirdPartySDK` variable (it is declared in the script executed through `eval`).

You can then import ThirdPartySDK through the wrapper module:

```ts
import ThirdPartySDK from './wrapper';
ThirdPartySDK.foo();  // Console output: "Hello, world!"
```

Note that this wrapper only works for applications running in Node.js, since it uses `fs.fileReadSync` to get the contents of the script.

If you're going to use it in a browser, you will need some other way to retrieve the script. You could probably use frameworks such as WebPack to bundle the ThirdPartySDK script as a string value that you can `require` in the wrapper module.

Comment: In the browser unfortunately. I'm a little surprised there is no standard solution for this considering how many IIFE modules used to be kicking around.

Comment: @ZacDelventhal: Okay, so which module loader are you using? It shouldn't be too hard to adapt this approach to also work in the browser.

Comment: It's an Angular 6/TypeScript front-end using webpack.

Comment: @ZacDelventhal: I haven't played around with Angular or Webpack in a long time (it was Angular 2.0 back then), but I could try experimenting a little to find out the details for how to make my approach work there, if that's what it's going to take for you to accept my answer :-) In the meantime, you might want to edit the question to include this requirement and also add the `webpack` tag.

Comment: Haha. I like your answer, but I don't think it is ideal, at least given my tool chain. I am playing around with an angular/webpack solution now, and will post it if I get it working. Took your advice and updated the tags/title/description to reflect the whole tool chain though.