# How to use save-svg-as-png with angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular7, iife

I am trying to use the [save-svg-as-png](https://www.npmjs.com/package/save-svg-as-png) library with my angular 7 project.

However, I cannot manage to get it to work. I have installed the library using

```
npm install --save save-svg-as-png
```

and I can see the library under node_modules.

Unfortunately, the library is an old-style javascript library and I do not know what I need to do in order to have access to it in my typescript components.

The readme refers to the [Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) library for which [type definitions](https://github.com/martianov/typed-save-svg-as-png) apparently exist. However, the Typings page mentions that it is deprecated for TypeScript 2, so I did not pursue this.

Apparently there is [@types/save-svg-as-png](https://www.npmjs.com/package/types-save-svg-as-png?activeTab=readme) for native Angular 2+ support, but when I try to install it with

```
npm install --save @types/save-svg-as-png
```

the library cannot be found (`npm ERR! code 404`).

I googled some more and came across [this issue on github](https://github.com/LINCnil/pia/issues/252) where somebody has apparently got it working with Angular 2 by including it in the angular-cli.js file, but with the changes to Angular, this file no longer exists in version 7 and I do not know how that would need to be done nowadays.

I've also found the [following article on how to integrate javascript libraries into Angular 2+](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-javascript-libraries-in-angular-2-apps-ff274ba601af), but most of it relies on @types being available (which they are not, see above) and only has a brief section on how to supply your own `typings.d.ts` file but after playing around for quite a while, I did not get any further. Is there a more detailed explanation showing how to use this approach?

I've also found this [article on stackoverflow on how to integrate IIFE based libraries into typescript apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54225603/how-do-i-import-an-iife-based-javascript-module-into-an-angular-typescript-app) but did not get it working.

I've added the following line to my `index.html` file

```
<script type="javascript" src="node_modules/save-svg-as-png/lib/saveSvgAsPng.js"></script>
```

but how do I now access the functions provided by the library? If I understood things correctly, they should now be available on the window object, but that does not seem to be the case.

I've also read this [stackoverflow question on how to use non typescript libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417107/how-use-an-external-non-typescript-library-from-typescript-without-d-ts/27434010#27434010) but one of my problems is that I don't even know into what namespace `save-svg-as-png` is being imported.

Has anyone managed to get this library working with an Angular 6/7 project and could give a detailed explanation on all steps required?

Comment: If it is installed, you can try to import it in your component as: import * as saveSvgAsPgn from 'saveSvgAsPng';

Comment: Actually, it needed to be `import * as svg from 'save-svg-as-png';`, but now I can access its methods (though IntelliJ does offer auto-completion on method names).

Comment: Correct, it needs to have the ' ' around it. My bad.

Comment: The '' were there the first time round :-) However, the library name needs to be kebab-case instead of camel-case. No worries!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll try to summarise the solution as suggested by Hypenate:

Install the library:

```
npm install --save save-svg-as-png
```

At the top of my typescript file/angular component:

```
import * as svg from 'save-svg-as-png';
```

Using it in my angular component:

```
svg.svgAsPngUri(document.getElementById('idOfMySvgGraphic'), {}, (uri) => {
      console.log('png base 64 encoded', uri);
    });
```

All exported functions are available on `svg`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, we can use the saveSvgAsPng.js file as an external js file instead of installing that package

1. Add saveSvgAsPng.js file into src/assets/js
2. And add this JavaScript file in scripts array in angular.json file

`"scripts": [ "src/assets/js/saveSvgAsPng.js" ]`

3. declare saveSvgAsPng in your component.ts

`declare const saveSvgAsPng: any;`

4. And call that when you need to download.

`saveSVG(): void{ saveSvgAsPng(document.getElementById('id'), fileName); }`

Make sure to restart your angular app (`ng serve`) if you change scripts array or declared name

Answer (score 0):

You can define a type for it. In the below example, I define a type for the saveSvgAsPng method, but you can define another type.

```js
declare module "save-svg-as-png" {
    const saveSvgAsPng: (el: HTMLElement, filename: string) => void;
    export { saveSvgAsPng };
}
```