# How to import a var initialized by an IIFE in JS File to a TS class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, grafana, iife

My final goal is to integrate steelseries.js (https://github.com/HanSolo/SteelSeries-Canvas) in a Grafana plugin written in react. A long way to go ...
Currently, I am trying to import the `steelseries` var in a ts class.
To sum up, I have a **JS** file (more than 10 000 lines) that has the following structure :

```
var helloWorld = (function() {

    var helloDisplay = function () {
        console.log("Hello World");
    }
    return {msgDisplay : helloDisplay}

}) ();
```

And I want to import it in a **TS** class like that :

```
// how to import my JS script in myJs ?

class MyClass {
    ...
    tsHello (): void {
        myJs.msgDisplay()
    }
}
```

What is the simplest and/or the most efficient way to do that (JS File is very long)?
(My class is in a TS file. I tried many things, I added .d.ts file but without success).

Comment: have you tried to `export default class MyClass{...}`?

Comment: @Lhew. The problem is not to export MyClass. I know how to do that. The problem is importing the JS variable `helloWorld` that is initialized by an IIFE and contains field inside that are functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use javascript in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318542/how-to-use-javascript-in-typescript)

Comment: @Peter.Thanks for answer.  I read it but my problem is the IIFE. I think the solution is here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/54225603/7462275). See my comment in the Lhew answer. Do you think, the solution is in this post ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, it is the best way but it works and it is simple.

1. tsconfig.json file :
   `"compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es6",
        "strict": true,
    }`
2. In js file : add export
   `export var helloWorld = (function() { ...`
3. Create a .d.ts file with same name as the js file
   `export var helloWorld: any;`
4. Import it in the ts file
   `import { helloWorld as myJs } from './varIIFE'
    class MyClass {
        tsHello () {myJs.msgDisplay()}
    }
   let myInstance = new MyClass();
   myInstance.tsHello()`
5. Add module attribute in index.html to the generated js file
   `<script src="compilatedfile.js" type="module"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```
interface HelloWorld{
  msgDisplay():void,
  foo:string,
  baz: number
}

var helloWorld = (function():HelloWorld {

  var helloDisplay = function () {
      console.log("Hello World");
  }
  return {
    msgDisplay : helloDisplay,
    foo: 'bar',
    baz: 123
  }

})()
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. The problem there are a lot of return fields. I want to use the steelseries.js file (https://github.com/HanSolo/SteelSeries-Canvas) in a react application written in tsx. In read a post where fs and eval() is used (https://stackoverflow.com/q/54225603/7462275) but I did not succeed to use it. I am working on it.